# Conversion error in numpy.loadtxt()

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to plot two columns from a text file using python matplotlib but I am getting

> ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 148.000000;

This is my python script

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x,y = np.loadtxt('sharma5.txt')
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

and here is a part of my text file

```
36.000000   61.000000
36.000000   61.000000
36.000000   148.000000;
36.000000   60.000000
36.000000   120.000000
36.000000   77.000000
36.000000   160.000000
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please remember to format your code using Ctrl-K!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you don't want to fix your data file, you can use the `converters` option to `loadtxt` in order to remove any extraneous semicolons.  Something like `np.loadtxt("sharma5.txt", converters = {1: lambda s: float(s.strip(";"))})` should work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the semicolon in your text file, which is not recognized as a legal character for converting to a number. Fix the bug in the program that generated that text file.