# Loading sparse matrix into python

Tags: python, file-io, sparse-matrix

I generated a sparse matrix in R and wrote in csv and it looks like

```
1   0   0   0 .
0   1   1   1 .
0   0   0   0 .
1   0   0   0 .
.............
```

and so on 
Then now when i am trying to load the csv through **numpy.loadtext**

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 841, in loadtxt
 items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
 ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
```

How can I read the csv?

Comment: Can you show the code where you call loadtxt?

Comment: sp=numpy.loadtxt("C:/Users/rohit.gupta/Desktop/sparse_mat.csv")

Comment: Why you have some dots in your CSV? This dots cannot be parsed by `numpy.loadtxt()` (see: [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989522/conversion-error-in-numpy-loadtxt)).

Comment: Is the csv format exactly as written here? Or are they maybe float values where the decimal seperator is `,`? That could explain why a long string with lots of commas is passed to float.